# Jcarousal not working in wordpress

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, jcarousel

I am experiencing a serious issue where my jcarousal plugin stopped working in wordpress.
You can see 'Our Partners' Section in homepage of http://www.entuple.com

Please tell me how to solve the issue.

It is happening after I installed and deleted some random plugins.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  there is no clear indication that it is a programming problem.

Comment: Plus it does seem to be working on the site

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I am able to solve the issue and that's why its working in site. Thanks for the concern.